# startActivityForResult dentro de um adapter?

Tags: android

Boa noite galera.

Meu cenario é o seguinte: Na Activity A, preencho uma lista atraves em um RecycleView com um ArrayList retornado do meu WebService. O Layout desta lista tem uma imagem, um titulo e um botão para cada item. O botão faz o papel de follow/unfollow, ou seja quando ele é clicado (mudo seu icone e salvo  o status via webservice), ele segue ou deixa de seguir um outro usuario da lista. Quando eu clico na imagem, eu vou pro Perfil do usuario referente ao item da lista. Ok, até ai tudo bem, funcionando perfeitamente.

Quando entro no perfil do Usuario (Activity B), lá também tem o botão de follow/unfollow. Então, basicamente quero que, se o botão follow/unfollow seja clicado no perfil do usuario (Activity B), e a pessoa retorne a lista de usuarios(Activity A) o valor do botão referente ao item seja atualizado na lista.

Pensei em usar startActivityForResult, mas não consigo chama-la dentro do meu adapter que é onde trato o onclick do botão e da imagem. E não gostaria de recarregar a lista no onResume da Activity A.

Alguem tem alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embora você não consiga chamar o `startActivityForResult()` dentro do seu *adapter*, você pode registrar a `Activity A` como *listener* (*observer*) do *adapter*, de forma que quando a imagem for clicada o *adapter* informa a *Activity*, que por sua vez chama `startActivityForResult()`.

A forma de se fazer isso é bem simples, basta passar a `Activity A` como parâmetro no construtor do *adapter* e invocar um método público da mesma quando a imagem for clicada. Dentro da implementação desse método público você chama a `Activity B`.

Ao voltar para a `Activity A`, você pode atualizar o conteúdo da *RecyclerView* em `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Cara, foi exatamente isso que eu fiz. Obrigado pela resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

No xml do seu botão coloque android:onClick="nomeEvento"

e na Activity desta tela crie o método

```
public void nomeEvento(View botao){
    //faça o que quiser aqui
   //startActivityForResult...
}
```

Assim toda vez que qualquer dos botões for clicado será executado o método "nomeEvento"

Answer (score 0):

É um pouco tarde mas ainda pode ser útil.

No método *onClick* do ViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent data = new Intent(view.getContext(), OtherActivity.class);
    data.putExtra("POSITION", getAdapterPosition());
    ((Activity) view.getContext()).startActivityForResult(data, 1);
}
```

Exemplo enviando dados para outra Activity usando o **startActivityForResult** com RecyclerView.